# In Affinity Propagation do the cluster centres minimize mean distance to all other points in the cluster?

Tags: clustering

For Affinity Propagation, do the cluster centers minimize the mean distance to all other points in the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

AP maximizes responsibility, which is a combination of availability and affinity. Distances only serve as an indirect source to input affinities.

If you want to minimize average distance to the cluster center, use **PAM It minimizes the sum of distances to the representatives**, and that is equivalent because the number of points is constant.